# Creating plots with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new to R and now I am trying to use ggplot to create some graphs.
However, I proably did not understand the logic fully, because I have some problems now:

For example, I have the following dataframe which I alrady reshaped:

```
     id variable value
1     1 Var1     1
2     1 Var2     1
3     2 Var1     NA
4     2 Var2     NA
5     3 Var1     1
6     3 Var2     NA
7     4 Var1     NA
8     4 Var2     1
...
```

Now, I want to produce a simple plot (like a barplot) that adds up the values for each of the two varaibles.
Howver, I do not get any sensible results...

In a second data frame, my data looks different

```
     id variable value
1     1 Var1     4
2     2 Var1     5
3     3 Var1     2
4     4 Var1     5
5     5 Var1     3
6     6 Var1     1
7     7 Var1     5
8     8 Var1     4
...
```

Here I would also like to get a barplot, but here I would like to get the percentage shares of the values as bars.
E.g. 20% said 5, 30% said 4, ... I tried this by calculatiing the percentage shares in advance, but then I wanted to add the number of observations under each bar, which did not work out, because I only had the percentages left in my dataframe. Is there a way to get the sahres as bars, but the number of observations under each bar?

I guess that should not be so diffucult, but I have problems with the logic behind ggplot...

Any help would be highly appreciated! I also checked other posts, but could not find a way that was working.

Thank you very much in adavance!

Comment: Please share a `dput(your_data)` so others can get it easily into R. "I have problems with ggplot" What have you tried? Additionally, it seems that you are asking for more than one plot, what are your expected outputs ?

Comment: Thank you for your totally correct feedback! I understand that it is necessary to improve the understanding of the issues! I will keep this in mind for the future cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [u/Matias Andina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215940/matias-andina) mentioned, you should provide a bit more information about your particular question and post your code attempts so that we can help you.  However, I can demonstrate using an example similar to the example dataset you posted and how to create a bar graph.

**geom_bar() vs. geom_col()**

First of all, note that `ggplot` has two `geoms` that you can use to create "bar graphs".  In this case, "`geoms`" refer to the geometries that are applied to the chart area to "draw out" your actual plot: `geom_line` for the lines on a line chart, `geom_point` to display the points on a scatter plot, etc.

For bar charts, [see this documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html), which describes the differences between `geom_bar` and `geom_col`: both of which create bar graphs.  In a nutshell:

- `geom_bar` makes the height of the bar proportional to the number of cases in a group
- `geom_col` makes the height of the bar proportional to the value of the cases in a group

**Examples of both**

Here's my own dataset, modeled after the one you posted:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id=c(1:7),
    variable = c('var1', 'var1', 'var1', 'var1', 'var2', 'var2', 'var2'),
    value =c(1,1,3,2,4,5,2))
```

`geom_bar` plots the number of cases in a group--in this case, the number of times "var1" and "var2" appear in the dataset in the "variable" column.  For a `geom_bar` plot, therefore, we only specify what's on the ***x-axis***, and the y-axis values are calculated by the `stat` method built into the `geom_bar` method.  In this case, to create the plot, it's pretty simple:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Note that we only specified "variable" on the x-axis, which is done by applying it to `aes()`, conveniently within the `ggplot()` call, but you can also do that within `geom_bar()` if you prefer--it's just best practice to put it in `ggplot()` if it applies to the whole plot.  Notice that on the y-axis, the "count" of each are represented--not the value total.  In fact, if you specify a value for x and y within `aes()` and attempt to use a `geom_bar`, you will see an error related to the stat method (`stat_count()`) used in `geom_bar` because it can't apply the method properly.

`geom_col` plots the value of each variable, so the only difference is that you need to specify within `aes()` the x- and y-axis columns, but otherwise it's still very simple:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

If you have a more specific question, please indicate with the output of your data (post the output of `dput(your.data.frame)`), and please also post your own code that you've tried with the results and a description of what your expected results would be.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer! It was not only solving my issues, but also was helping me in understanding ggplot better! I also managed to get shares on the y-axis, which was the only thing I could not get straight away out of your answer by adding `geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))` to my plots.

Comment: Yes - with that you are overwriting the default `stat_count` method that is used.  To my mind I believe you can also do that within `geom_bar` via: `geom_bar(stat=...)` to specify the stat method to use... but honestly have not had too much experience trying that approach myself yet.